# How to have two character integers less than 10 in JSON?

Tags: json, numbers, integer

I'm working with JSON, but I am somewhat new to it.

I'm trying to pad numbers to two characters because that makes the whole thing a lot easier and more uniform.

However, this makes numbers less than 10 throw the error "Expected comma".

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this/what the best workaround is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal
> and hexadecimal formats are not used.

[image]

Numbers like: `01`, `02`, ... are not allowed.